# The multi-part identifier "CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I am running this query and getting "The multi-part identifier "CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code" could not be bound."

what am i doing wrong can some one help ?

Thanks,

```
select top 100 

[CM_PayorMaster].[Payor_Parent_Code],

[CM_PayorPlanMap].[Mnumber],

CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Code,

CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Parent_Code,

CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code

From (CM_PayorMaster

 Left join  CM_PayorPlanMap on CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Plan_Code=CM_PayorPlanMap.Payor_Plan_Code)

inner join CM_PayorParentText on CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Plan_Code=CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code)
```

Comment: Your query does not seem to use MySQL. I have changed the tag to SQL Server. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: At the very least, you have unbalanced parentheses, but even so, that's not how the FROM clause works... if you want to select FROM a sub-select, the sub-select needs a SELECT statement too... but maybe just remove that first opening paren, and both closing ones, because I'm not sure what they're for.

Comment: Thanks for your help .. It worked after the edits .

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is you are selecting the column `CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code` and you aren't joining to the `CM_PayorPlanText` table. You *are* joining to `CM_PayorParentText`, which is the `Parent` which seems to be the confusion.

Based on the `JOIN` clause, I think you likely want to replace `CM_PayorParentText` with `CM_PayorPlanText`

You also have unbalanced parentheses... I removed them since they aren't needed.

```
select top 100
    [CM_PayorMaster].[Payor_Parent_Code],
    [CM_PayorPlanMap].[Mnumber],
    CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Code,
    CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Parent_Code,
    CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code        
From
    CM_PayorMaster
Left join 
    CM_PayorPlanMap on 
    CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Plan_Code=CM_PayorPlanMap.Payor_Plan_Code
inner join 
    CM_PayorPlanText on   --changed the table here                  
    CM_PayorMaster.Payor_Plan_Code=CM_PayorPlanText.Payor_Plan_Code
```

Also, you are using `TOP 100` without an `ORDER BY` which means you don't care *which* non-deterministic 100 rows should be returned. If you think you will get the same 100 each time, you should read [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171443/95107) with emphasis on [this post.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Comment: Awesome .. thanks a lot it worked . i was overlooking the table names .. Thanks a lot .. I only ran top 100 to test the query if it work properly since there are over 500K records and I was trying to save time . Thanks ..

Comment: No sweat @SyedGillani. Be sure to [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) since you are new.